# mongodb with short life cycle

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We are running mongodb to store huge amount of objects(~1 000 000 a day) with short lifetime( ~15 minutes). Total virtual mem(== db files size) usage is ~50gb daily.  Current workflow looks like this:

1. Store object
2. Delete old objects every 15 mins
3. Run repair at night time - server hangs for ~20 minutes while reparing.

Could you please suggest if mongo is suitable for short living objects. If yes - which config settings should we change against default config. If no - which nosql(document based, as we store JSON like objects) solution should be used.

Thanks

Comment: I think memecached suit your need. Although it's not document based).But you can store the json encode string in the value. And it has built in expire function.

Comment: Use <s>the force Luke</s> Redis

Comment: Why redis? Which advantages does it provide?

Comment: Why do you run repair? MongoDB should reuse the space that was used by the deleted objects with the new objects. Redis has TTL functionality. MongoDB will too soon : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-211

Comment: Probably MongoDB should reuse space, but it doesn't. .db files are growing and growing.

Answer (score 3):

A [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) might be a good choice for this usage if you can estimate the size well.  You create a capped collection explicitly rather than implicitly as you do with normal collections, and you specify a maximum size.  As new documents are added to the capped collection, old ones are deleted automatically.  Space usage is constant, deletes are implicit and there is nothing to repair at the end of the day.  The downside would be if your size needs are actually growing, because you would need to create new (larger) capped collections to maintain the same lifetime of documents.

A future possibility is described in "TTL collections" ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-211 ) .  This feature is not in any shipped version but might be exactly what you need, making your maintenance automatic.  You can "watch" the feature and vote for it on the page I linked to, but it is scheduled for the next release.

Comment: Tad, capped is almost what we need, except one point - capped collections cannot be updated with size changing.

Comment: So don't update? Insert a newer version of the object instead and use filter, sort, limit, et cetera to only get the latest.